# how to get database value from orm and field name get from string in odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I get field name string from configuration.

```
para = 'partner_id.name'
account.invoice(281088,).para 
*** AttributeError: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'para'
```

The system cannot know database field name exactly.It comes from user configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can split the provided parameter and use `getattr` like this

```
para = 'partner_id.name'
attributes = para.split('.')
value = account.invoice(281088)
for attribute in attributes:
    if hasattr(value, attribute):
        value = getattr(value, attribute)
    else:
        return False
return value
```

```
attributes = para.split('.')
```

This splits user supplied parameter. In this case attributes value will become `['partner_id', 'name']`

```
value = account.invoice(281088)
```

Assign account.invoice to value

```
for attribute in attributes:
    if hasattr(value, attribute):
        value = getattr(value, attribute)
    else:
        return False
```

Loop through our attributes and check if value has that attribute. If so, get its value or return else otherwise.

```
return value
```

Return the finale value which will be partner name in this case